# Elasticsearch succeeds for partial match and fails for exact match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a value in the "handle" field of my users index. Let's say the exact string of this value is "exactstring". My query will return the correct result for "exactstrin" but it will fail (return nothing) for "exactstring". N-grams, like "actstr", also return the correct result. WTF?

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": ["handle","name","bio"],
                    "prefix_length": 2,
                    "query": "exacthandle",
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            }],
            "should" : [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": ["handle^6", "name^3", "bio"],
                    "query": "exacthandle"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "size": 100,
    "from": 0
}
```

Here's my settings:

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "search_term_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "stopwords": "_none_",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "no_stop"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                },
                "ngram_token_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "stopwords": "_none_",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "no_stop",
                        "ngram_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "no_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": "_none_"
                },
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": "2",
                    "max_gram": "9"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And my mappings:

```
"handle": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
},
"name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
},
"bio": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/multi-fields.html) to solve this. Querying the field "handle.text" now returns exact string matches of arbitrary length.

I was also able to create ngram and edge_ngram filters with different min and max grams and then use them simultaneously.

The mapping looks like this now:

```
"handle": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    },
    "text": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "edge_ngram": { 
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "edge_ngram_token_analyzer"
    },
    "ngram": { 
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "ngram_token_analyzer"
    }
  }
}
```

The multi-match query can now simultaneously use different analyzers on the same field (the big difference between the must and should queries comes down to fuzziness, the bio field tends to contain a lot of small tokens and fuzziness produces a lot of bad hits):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must" : [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                        "handle.text^6", 
                        "handle.edge_ngram^4", 
                        "handle.ngram^2",
                        "bio.text^6", 
                        "bio.keyword^4",
                        "name.text^6", 
                        "name.keyword^5", 
                        "name.edge_ngram^2", 
                        "name.ngram^3"
                        ],
                    "query": "exactstring",
                    "prefix_length": 2
                }
            }],
            "should" : [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                        "handle.text^6", 
                        "handle.edge_ngram^2", 
                        "handle.ngram^1",
                        "name.text^6", 
                        "name.keyword^5", 
                        "name.edge_ngram^2", 
                        "name.ngram^3"
                        ],
                    "query": "exactstring",
                    "prefix_length": 2,
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "size": 100,
    "from": 0
}
```

For completeness, here are the settings of my index:

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "search_term_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "stopwords": "_none_",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "no_stop"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                },
                "ngram_token_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "stopwords": "_none_",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "no_stop",
                        "ngram_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                },
                "edge_ngram_token_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "stopwords": "_none_",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "no_stop",
                        "edge_ngram_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "no_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": "_none_"
                },
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": "3",
                    "max_gram": "12"
                },
                "edge_ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": "3",
                    "max_gram": "50"
                }
            }
        },
        "max_ngram_diff": 50
    }
```

h/t to @bhavya for max_ngram_diff

Answer (score 0):

This must be happening because you have set less value for `max_gram`(Maximum length of characters in a gram). When you are querying for `exactstring`, then the tokens generated for `exactstring`, will have a maximum token of length 9 (i.e `exactstri`). Due to this, the query will match on `exactstri` and not on `exactstring`.

> You need to [specify the analyzer of the field](http://When%20mapping%20an%20index,%20you%20can%20use%20the%20analyzer%20mapping%20parameter%20to%20specify%20an%20analyzer%20for%20each%20text%20field.). When mapping an
> index, you can use the analyzer mapping parameter to specify an
> analyzer for each text field.If none of the analyzers is specified,
> then the `standard analyzer` is used.

You also need to increase the `max_gram` to at least `11` for `ngram_token_analyzer` in your index setting. And also set `"max_ngram_diff": "20"`. The tokens generated (which you can check using [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)) will have `exactstrin` as well as `exactstring` and now your query will match on both `exactstrin` and `exactstring`

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "search_term_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "stopwords": "_none_",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "no_stop"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        },
        "ngram_token_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "stopwords": "_none_",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "no_stop",
            "ngram_filter"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "no_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_none_"
        },
        "ngram_filter": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "11"               <-- note this
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 20
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "handle": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_token_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "handle":"exactstring"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "handle",
              "name",
              "bio"
            ],
            "prefix_length": 2,
            "query": "exactstring",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64957062",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6292809,
        "_source": {
          "handle": "exactstring"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @James Moffet did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: hi @bhavya, I don't think this is what I'm looking for. This solution will still fail for longer strings. I need exact string matches to be returned regardless of their length. Using an arbitrarily high number for max_gram is unacceptable because the memory required scales unfavorably as that number increases

Comment: @JamesMoffet thanks for your reply. Can you please give an example of where this solution will fail?

Comment: Hi @bhavya, this solution (max_gram: 11) fails for a value like "thisismyverylongstring", in order to succeed for this value, max_gram would need to be ~21 (depending on fuzziness). I ended up solving this with multi-fields, check my solution below, I will accept it when the waiting period is over

Comment: @JamesMoffet glad you figured it out :) And please don't forget to upvote my answer if it helped you :)